# How to you reference an array in a different .java file from a another .java file?

Tags: java

Im a but confused. I want to add more data into the library however i want to collect the data from another .java file from where the library is defined.

the library code is as followed:

```
private static Map<String, Item> library = new TreeMap<String, Item>();

static {

    library.put("01", new Item("Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "Hello",
            "Kate@redwich.ac.uk", "How is the course going?", 2));
    library.put("02", new Item("Kate@redwich.ac.uk", "Re: Hello",
            "Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "> How is the course going?\n\nBrilliant, thanks. The students are all fantastic and are going to get top marks in their coursework.", 2));
    library.put("03", new Item("A.Friend@hmail.com", "Coffee",
            "Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "You're working too hard - fancy meeting for coffee?.", 5));
    library.put("04", new Item("Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "Exam",
            "Asif@redwich.ac.uk", "I have nearly finished writing the exam - I hope the students have revised hard.", 4));
    library.put("05", new Item("A.Student@redwich.ac.uk", "Timetable",
            "Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "help!!! my timetable is rubbish - i cant understand it!!! what r u going to do?", 0));
    library.put("06", new Item("Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "Re: Timetable",
            "A.Student@redwich.ac.uk", "Please ignore the timetables on the portal - just follow the advice on TeachMat.", 0));
    library.put("07", new Item("A.Student@redwich.ac.uk", "Re: Timetable",
            "Chris@redwich.ac.uk", "thx :)", 0));
```

The data I wish to import from another .java file code looks like this:

```
public String[] MessageData2(){
    String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
    String subject = subjectText.getText();
    String recipient = recipientText.getText();
    String message = messageArea.getText();
    String [] messageData1 = {"0","1","2"};
    messageData1 [0] = messageId;
    messageData1 [1] = subject;
    messageData1 [2] = recipient;
    messageData1 [3] = message;

    return messageData1;
```

it needs to follow the same convention as the previous.
What I have tried doing is this:

```
library.put(messageData1[0], new Item(messageData1[2], messageData1[1],
               messageData1[2], messageData1[3], 0));
```

can anyone help?

Joe

Comment: You could change `library` from `private` to `public`...but this general design is not advisable.

Comment: @bdkosher, the imports are to be done from second code excerpt.

Comment: @Tanay not sure what you're getting at. Anytime a mutable collection field is publicly exposed, there are risks--security, thread-safety, memory consumption, etc.

Comment: @bdkosher, Yes I agree, but the Map here is private.

Comment: @Tanay ....the Map is private unless it were made public in order to allow another class to modifying it.....which is not advisable, as we both agree.

Answer (score 1):

// in a seperate file classA.java

```
public classA
{
    // always when creating a classA object a empty TreeMap (your decision)
    private Map<String, Item> library = new TreeMap<String, Item>();

    public setLibrary(Map<String, Item> library)
    {
        this.libray = libray
    }
    public getLibrary()
    {
        return this.library;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an Object like:

```
classA a = new ClassA();
a.getLibrary.put(....);
```

It really depends on the your whole strucrute. But setters/getters are a fundamental concept.

Comment: The getter and setter should either perform a copy, or a `put` method should be implemented on `ClassA` directly (rather than exposing the underlying `Map`).

Comment: Yeah that's also possible. But maybe he wants to pass this library somewhere else. I really don't know his whole structure. Of course if you just need the library internally, then your solution would be better.